# why I got java.lang.RntimeException: Internal error in cloud FireStore(24.4.4)

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, google-cloud-firestore, crash

I'm on creting a flutter application that recieve data from other device via Ble Low Energy using FlutterBlePlus But after some time I got why I got java.lang.RntimeException: Internal error in cloud FireStore(24.4.4) with an application crash

this is the implementation in build.gradle:

```
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.4.4'
```

in pubspec.yaml:

```
  cloud_firestore: ^4.3.1
  firebase_core: ^2.4.1
```

Comment: Where did you get `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.4.4'` did you add it manually?

Comment: @flutroid I added it manually but I found the version in maven repository https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-firestore